# php imagick doesn't support any formats

Tags: php, imagick

I am trying to install imagick and this is the error that appears:

> NoDecodeDelegateForThisImageFormat

Now imagick seems to be installed correctly but when i go to phpinfo() this is what appears:

> ImageMagick number of supported formats:  0
>
> ImageMagick supported formats no value

Can anyone tell me how to fix this and add all the formats ? Or at least an alternative to imagick if there is no other option ?

Comment: Would need details on the install to know what went awry.  Obvious alternative to Imagick is [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).  I prefer Imagick.

Comment: You are almost certainly installing a version of Imagick that was compiled against a different version of ImageMagick than you have installed. Try downloading them from http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/deps/ http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/imagick/3.3.0rc2/

Comment: @Danack Am I missing something? How can you tell OP uses Windows?

Comment: @MarkSetchell because for people using Linux (or other *nix variants) their package manager would not install a mismatch of packages. This problem has only ever been reported by Windows users.

Comment: @Danack Aha! Thanks for taking the time to enlighten me.